# Object movement issue

Tags: java

I am trying to make a square object  move to the right, instead, it increases in size making it longer. There seems to be an issue with the rendering.

Render code:

```
private void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null) {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    final Color background = new Color(201, 133, 30);
    g.setColor(background);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    
    handler.render(g);
    handler.addObject(new Player(100, 100, ID.Player));
    handler.addObject(new Player(200, 250, ID.Player));
    
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Changing .createBufferStrategy(3) to .createBufferStrategy(1) seemed to help. The square looks now as rectangle that is moving, is not appearing to grow endlessly any more, and sometimes it flickers showing the path it took.

Comment: Code looks fine, but I wonder, does it really grow, or is it possible that you don't cleanup the canvas correctly and the old 32x32 squares remain there, so when moving it, it looks like it grows.

Comment: l was wondering about that as well, added the render code in my question. Thank you for your time!

Comment: All edited properly now.